# Creating Simple Splash screen without photoshop knowledge( Ionic/Cordova )

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen

I want to create a splashscreen image/psd. This has to be 2048x2048 resolution.
It will be a just an image on the center of the page with a background color.
How to do this without getting lost in photoshop. Any ideas will greatly help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go for more flexible option yet without getting your hands dirty on complex implementation then this lib will greatly help you out.

https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AwesomeSplash

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at: https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/

In effect you create a Drawable XML, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Then in your Style Values:

```
<style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/background_splash</item>
</style>
```

Create a new Activity (Blank) and make it your Start activity (in Android Manifest):

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Teh 'SplashActivity' should just forward you to your MainActivity; something like:

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Note that you do not inflate a view at all! You use the Window background from your `style` to do the work.